# CORS filtering allowed all at Spring boot Not Working

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I have A spring boot application where I allowed all request for CORS filter.

```
    @Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");

}
```

And from angular JS I called some rest api of this server app. BUt I am getting following error

```
Failed to load http://localhost:10230/place: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

My angular call like this

```
 function savePlace(place) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{'X-TenantID': 'freight_management'},
        data: place,
        url: 'http://localhost:10230/place'
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
    }, function (reason) {
        return reason;
    });
}
```

How can I solve this?? Anything missing???

Comment: It says **header is missing** and I cannot see where you explicitly allow the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: This configuration works from my one PC but not another in different network

Comment: It requests localhost so the other machine needs to run the application locally as well. ...independent of the network...

Comment: I run on other machine. Both server and frontend. But it works on one pc but not in another

Comment: Do you use the same browser on both machines?

Comment: Yes from chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the allowed origins:

```
registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:63342");
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I solve it by using a proxy today, I used to face this problem like this.

This allows every origin.

This is stored within `CorsFilter.java`.

```
@Component
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, content-type, X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token, x-xsrf-token");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```